# How to remove entries in a list starting from nth position?

Tags: c#, list

How can I remove entries from a list of strings starting from nth position?

Which means if I have a list containing 10 elements, and if n=7, I need remove the 8th, 9th and 10th entries and get only the first 7 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) method. Or use LINQ to create a new list with only the elements satisfying your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
var firstSeven = list.Take(7);
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `list.RemoveRange` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the LINQ [`.Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method, which wouldn't directly affect the original collection, like so

```
var fewerStrings = myCollectionOfStrings.Take(n);
```

Additionally, if you wanted to select a range of items within a collection, you could combine this with the [`.Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension method

```
var fewerStrings = myCollectionOfStrings.Skip(n).Take(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use List.RemoveRange:

```
int index = 7;
lst.RemoveRange(index,lst.Count-index);
```

[List.RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5)

Answer (score 0):

Only select what you need, you can use [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var list   = new List<String>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
var result = list.Take(7).ToList(); // a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
```

Another way is using [List.RemoveRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx):

```
result = list.RemoveRange(6, 3)
```